# How can I give a child element of one parent a higher z-index than another parent?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a sidebar split into two divs with an equal z-index.

The first div, `top`, has a link that shows another div, `hover` when you hover over it.

`hover` extends down into the bottom div, `bottom`, but since `top` and `bottom` have the same z-index, `hover` is covered by `bottom`.

No matter how high of a z-index I give `bottom`, that only affects how it is displayed within `top`. How can I get it to cover up `bottom`?

By the way, I also want to do the same thing to `bottom`, so there will be a `bottom-hover` that should cover up `top`.

So giving `top` and `bottom` different z-indexes isn't an option.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/tsnuh7q1/

**html:**

```
<div class="top">top
    <div class="hover">HOVER</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom<div>
```

**css:**

```
.top {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
.hover {
    z-index: 40;
    width: 170px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    left: 30px;
}
.bottom {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Will you post some code here or create Fiddle.

Comment: @ketan I added a Fiddle.

Comment: @ketan It should be: Will you post some code here, and optionally create a fiddle too?

Comment: @JoeMorano Normally you can't, but there is a not so obvious trick: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child `z-index` is always in the context of the parent.

Take

```
#A { z-index: 1; }
#B { z-index: 2; }

#A * { z-index: 1000; }
```

children of `#A` will always be under `#B` and it's children. The context of their `z-index` is a lower layer.

Comment: Surely it has to be possible somehow to place a child of A above B?? I can't imagine the writers of CSS wouldn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Came accross this question whilst searching for a solution for my own issue. Couldn't help but giving it a go.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do why not do it like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/tsnuh7q1/2/

```css
.top,
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}
.bottom {
  background: green;
}
.hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
a:hover .hover {
  display: block;
}
.bottom .hover {
  top: initial;
  left: initial;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.top:hover,
.bottom:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">top
  <a href="#0">link<div class="hover">HOVER</div></a>
</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom
  <a href="#0">link<div class="hover">HOVER</div></a>
  <div>
```